# What technology can I use to write one view for my C# application?

Tags: c#, android, ios, jquery-mobile, user-interface

I'll soon be looking into writing a small business workflow application that I'd like my userbase to use across all devices - iOS Tablet, Windows PC, Windows Tablet, Mac, Android Tablet are the key targets.

I'm fairly new to the 'app' dev space and I don't know much about what frameworks and industry standards are forming around PC and mobile friendly applications, if any?

I'll be writing the core of the application in C# and I'm looking for technologies (HTML5, JS, etc) and even frameworks (I saw Xamarin might be okay?) that implement the View of the application. The tighter its tied to C# the better it'll be for me and the cleaner the transition between my chosen platforms the better.

Comment: Not necessarily - It won't be remotely hosted. All local to the device.

Comment: mobile web-app doesn't require hosting, it use html5 and js make the app. You might take a look on phonegap, sencha touch etc.

Comment: HTML5, JS, CSS using Xamarin or PhoneGap should be a solid plan.

Comment: I read this question as being about what technology is available to allow a single UI implementation for a C# app across iOS, Android, Windows, OS X. That doesn't make it opinion-based.

Answer (score 2):

I just created one using Jquery Mobile, and an odata C# webservice. Its just what work wanted me to but I see the framework being used alot. So pretty much get the data with the webservice then use javascript and html5 to display it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your application in C#, and not implement it as a web service, then I think the only option is Xamarin for the iOS / Android platforms (and .NET / Mono on Windows / OS X).

This does not mean using a single technology for the View, though, as [Xamarin UI code is not portable across iOS and Android](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications) (this has pros and cons involving the age-old native feel versus shared UI debate).

If you are flexible on implementing it as a web service, then your server logic can be written  in C#, with a shared HTML 5 client across all platforms.

If you are flexible on using C#, then you have more options outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks. I think a web service might be the way to go. My only worry is how messy it might get to write the interface between C# and HTML5. Do you know if it is a common or mature practice to go this route?

Comment: If you want to make a web application using C#, then you can use ASP.NET. It is a mature practice. Check out http://www.asp.net/mobile for mobile web applications.